# Conceptually, is the single page web app more efficient than the web app that loads pieces of the page for every page?

Tags: web-applications, html, css, jsp

I searched a lot, but nobody seems to have explained this nor given a proper example.

I have a page like this:

[image]

My team says they want to design the code such that the `Title` section, `Menu` section and `Footer` sections would each be kept in separate `HTML` files and they'd have separate `JSP` files for every page, where each `JSP` file would dynamically load the `title.html`, `menu.html` and `footer.html` files using `JQuery`.

My suggestion to them was to use a single `JSP`/`HTML` file which already contains the `Title`, `Menu` and `Footer`, and just load the `Center` content dynamically (single page app).

**I have three questions:**
1. For a web app that needs to use as less network bandwidth as possible, is it better to use a single page app approach or the load-multiple-pieces-of-a-page approach? Percentage-wise, would it result in a large change in bandwidth if the `Title` only contained a small brand logo and text, and the `Menu` and `Footer` just contained text and styles.

2. If content is to be loaded dynamically into a page, since `frame` is deprecated and I hear that `iframe` is not encouraged, is an ordinary `div` the best option to load `Center` content or the `Title`, `Menu`, `Footer` etc. OR is there a better way to load it such that it'd work in `IE` too?
3. When pages are kept split as `title.html`, `menu.html` etc., do they have to contain the `<html>' and``tags or can they just contain the necessary``'s? Do the loaded`HTML` pages inherit the parent page's properties?

Comment: What about AJAX & websocket techniques?

Comment: Not very familiar with those. I've already tried with iframes, but the iframe borders don't disappear even after using `border: none`. So tried loading into `div` and it loads only some elements. Problem is, I have to take a decision in a few hours and proceed.

Comment: You should read more about AJAX & websocket & HTML5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, I find it very good to keep the 'title', 'menu' and 'footer' in independent files.

What I really wonder about is: **why don't you put them together on the server side???**

`<%@include file="title.jsp" %>
<%@include file="menu.jsp" %>
<%@include file="footer.jsp" %>`

**Don't worry about bandwith**

The difference between your two solutions will be negligible and I wouldn't worry about. Most browser will cahche the files and retrieve them only once anyway. Having a picture on your website would consume much more bandwith, so avoid any picture. You want to save bandwitdh right? ...just kidding. It's just not a place to worry about. Bandwitdh is cheap.

**There are much more important things to worry about**

**Is it safe?**

The more javascript you have on your site, the more likely things can go wrong. With the large diversity of browsers/OSes/devices, you must be careful! If your javascript breaks somewhere, because of you or a dependency, it may cause that nothing works anymore. ...and your users will *not* be happy if the navigation on your site doesn't work anymore.

*Taking this into account, your solution is more error-prone.*

**Is it webby?**

You know, bookmarking pages? History? Previous page? Share a link? ;) ...with dynamic loading, you don't get all that stuff ...or it's a lot of extra work and bug sources.

*Your solution doesn't provide that.*

**Is it maintainable?**

...you know, easy to read/understand/change. I personnally find it easier to serve full pages with normal links rather than understanding javascripted navigation. My 2 cents.

*I think your way is more complicated*

Single page web apps is a trendy concept, but not all that is new and shiny is better than good ol' stuff.

**Doing the "merging" on server side has several benefits**

- It's simple
- It's easy to understand
- It'll never break on the client because not javascript dependent
- It's good for SEO because crawlers can index you easely
- People can "bookmark" pages and so on, you know
- The page is fully loaded in a single request

Answer (score 3):

It would be interesting to know what your team thought about your suggestion. I think it's got a lot of merit. To answer your questions.

1. Bandwidth, for both options I would say that caching either on the end-user's browser or via an ADN or CDN would solve this problem for you. If a web application is getting three files: Title, Menu and Footer, that don't change then these can be cached. For both there will be the initial hit whilst everything is got for the first-time.
2. If you are using jQuery then the AJAX methods within it should enable you to write content into any tag you choose. DIVs should be fine.
3. Included files that form part of a web-page shouldn't have  and  tags, otherwise you'll have invalid HTML in the final page.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, but most browser already cache thing like image/css/js so the bandwidth saving wouldn't blow you mind but still no screen bleeping and less request is nice to have
2. iframe has it place but I think for your case, AJAX is the best. there's other technique like using knockout so server only send JSon (instead of partial view) and later it will be rendered into html by knockout.
3. if you don't want to use iframe html tag isn't necessary.